# Deploying to elastic beanstalk using gulp - Static files permissions issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, gulp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Recently I've had to change from using `eb deploy` to using a gulp task to deploy my project to AWS elastic beanstalk.

The reason for this is that I need to babel transform ES6 files to ES5. I don not want to commit the transformed files to our git and `eb deploy` uses the git-archive command to make the zip to deploy.

The transform and deploy works, I'm running into an issue with static files.

```
gulp.task('ebDeploy', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        './.ebextensions/**',                   // Include the .ebextensions folder
        './**/*.js',                            // Match all .js files
        '!./es6/**/*',                          // Exclude files in /es6 dir
        '!node_modules', '!node_modules/**',    // Exclude the node_modules folder and contained files
        '*.js',                                 // Include JS Files in the base dir
        'package.json',                         // Include this specific file in base dir
        './config/**',                          // Include everything under /config
        './public/**', './public/**/*',         // Include everything under /public
        './views/**/*.ejs'                      // Include all .ejs files under /views
    ], { base: './' })
        .pipe(print())
        .pipe(gulpEbDeploy({
            //name: 'my-application', // optional: If not set, the name from package.json will be used
            //version: '1.0.0', // optional: If not set, the version from package.json will be used
            timestamp: true, // optional: If set to false, the zip will not have a timestamp
            waitForDeploy: true, // optional: if set to false the task will end as soon as it starts deploying
            amazon: {
               // accessKeyId: "< your access key (fyi, the 'short' one) >", // optional
               // secretAccessKey: "< your secret access key (fyi, the 'long' one) >", // optional
               // signatureVersion: "v4", // optional
                region: 'eu-west-2',
                bucket: 'elasticbeanstalk',
                applicationName: 'foo',
                environmentName: 'bar'
            }
        }))
});
```

I have checked the zip that get's uploaded and it contains all the correct files. However it seems that `eb deploy` does something to permissions that i need to duplicate.

When I use `eb deploy` (after committing the /build files which I'm trying to prevent)
Everything works fine.

When I use my gulp task: I get the following error when trying to access static files.

```
06:49:28.81 server.js:98 | Global Error Handler
06:49:28.81 server.js:99 | { Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat '/var/app/current/public/css/default.css'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/var/app/current/public/css/default.css',
  expose: false,
  statusCode: 500,
  status: 500 }
```

What do I need to do to make these files work as intended.

Comment: Yes permissions - EB deploy runs as root AFAIK. Where do you invoke the gulp task from? Also I see this sort of task as belonging to a ci server. You can get your ci server to do all the processing you like and prepare an EB deployment package. This will also speed up your deploys.

Comment: I'm running it from my local development machine, don't have the resources currently to set up an ci server.

Comment: I mean, how do you invoke the gulp task on your EC2 instance to get that error?

Comment: I'm invoking the gulp task from my local machine and it deploys to ec2, however i get the permission issue when browsing the live, deployed site.